# Как перейти на первую строку для записи след массива в файл на Си?

Tags: c, массивы, файлы

Я считаю в цикле значения массива. Как после расчета очередного массива `аа` записывать его значения в один и тот же файл, как в примере:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int aa[5]={1,2,3,4,5};

int main()
{
    FILE* ff;
    ff = fopen("file.txt","w+");
    for (int j=0;j<5;j++) {
      for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        aa[i]+=j;
        fprintf(ff,"%d\n", aa[i]);
    }
    }
    fclose(ff);
}
```

Хочется получить следующий результат:

```
1 2 4 7  11
2 3 5 8  12 
3 4 6 9  13
4 5 7 10 14
5 6 8 11 15
```

Comment: запишите в новый файл, а потом подмените.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так устроит?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int aa[5]={1,2,3,4,5};

int main()
{
    FILE* ff;
    ff = fopen("file.txt","w+");
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<5; j++)
        {
            aa[i] += j;
            fprintf(ff,"%3d", aa[i]);
        }
        fprintf(ff,"\n");
    }
    fclose(ff);
}
```

Comment: а по столбцам никак? просто после этого я буду строить графики из этого файла...

Comment: А! я не обратил внимания... Смотрите теперь - я изменил код. Так годится?

Comment: Супер!!! То что нужно! Спасибо большое )))